# Iptables and counters

Tags: iptables, nat, traffic

I'm trying to use iptables counters with munin to monitor traffic of hosts on my local subnet. For each host I set up a rule like this:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -d $ip
```

This should count the packets going from firewall to $ip, correct?

I found out that this does not seem to count all packets. I start tcpdump on my router (Linux) and I see packets to $ip that are not counted.

For example I check number of packets for rule to my phone IP. I start tcpdump, refresh Gmail on my phoone, I see packets in tcpdump's output but iptables rule counters are not incremented. Then I open a web page on the same phone and the counters are incremented.

What could be the reason?

Comment: @ryekayo run iptables -L -v

Comment: Ah thanks, let me correct myself. ipchains investigates packets in the rules defined in iptables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` chain is used by packets output from the firewall itself.

The chain you want to use is `FORWARD`, which is used by packets forwarded by the firewall.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I read about this here http://backreference.org/2010/07/31/munin-traffic-accounting-with-iptables/ and here http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin-contrib/plugins/network/accounting_ and the examples don't mention FORWARD. Care the explain what would be the difference between counters for OUTPUT and FORWARD in my case?

Comment: `OUTPUT` chain applies only to packets that are sent from a program running inside the firewall, while `FORWARD` applies to packets forwarded by the firewall.